# Using ffmpeg to add presentation timestamp

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to add presentation timestamp given a known frame rate. While this does work it does seem to be deprecated. I'm running the command:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -i input.h264 -codec copy output.mp4
```

The error im getting is:

> Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and
>   will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps
>   properly

After googling around people were suggesting to use "-fflags +genpts" running the command below does however give the same error as above

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -r 24 -i test.h264 -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore that message. It has been around for a long time. The MP4 muxer will assign timestamps and that code won't be removed any time soon.